# Tuning ksvm from kernlab

Tags: r, kernlab

I want to use an SVM implementation in R to do some regression. I tried using `svm` from `e1071` already but I am limited by the kernel functions there. So I moved on to `ksvm` from `kernlab`. But I have a major disadvantage that a tuning function has not been provided in `kernlab` (like `tune.svm` in `e1071`). Can someone explain how do I tune the parameters for different kernels there?

PS. I want to particularly use the `rbfdot` kernel. So if at least someone can help me understand how to tune sigma, I'd be extremely grateful.

PPS. I'm completely aware that the `"automatic"` value for kpar can be used "*to calculate a good sigma*". But I need something more tangible and more along the lines of `tune.svm`.

Answer (score 2):

Either you write your own wrapper (wouldn't be that hard to be honest) or you could try already proven implemented solutions, like `mlr` and `caret`.

---

`mlr` tutorial has [an example about it](http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/tune/index.html).

```
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("C", values = 2^(-2:2)),
  makeDiscreteParam("sigma", values = 2^(-2:2))
)

ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()

rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L)

res = tuneParams("classif.ksvm", task = iris.task, resampling = rdesc, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
```

This will perform 3-fold cross-validation to select parameters from the grid and evaluate accuracy on the iris dataset. You can, of course, change resampling strategies (leave-one-out, monte-carlo CV, CV, repeated CV, bootstrap validation and holdout are all implemented), search strategy (grid search, random search, generalized simulated annealing and iterated F-race are all supported) and evaluation metrics.